# Images and formatting not working on a multi-tabbed XLSx file generated with ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, excel-2007, excel-2010, coldfusion-9, cfspreadsheet

The code below will generate the file with two notable errors:

1. The SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth appears to stop working after 21 lines on the second tab
2. The image does not appear on the second tab

Hopefully this is just a rookie mistake and not something along the lines of the date formatting issue. Any help or constructive criticism to fix/improve would be greatly welcomed.

```
<!--- We cannot directly reference the image --->
<cfimage source="img/A2LA_Logo.jpg" name="A2LA_Logo">
<!--- We need an absolute path, so get the current directory path.  --->
<cfset theFile=GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath()) & "Final_Report.xlsx">

<cfscript> 
/*********************************************************************** Page 1 ***********************************************************************/
//Create a new Excel spreadsheet object - SpreadsheetNew("Tab name", "yes=2007+ no=2003");
    Tab1 = SpreadsheetNew("Final Report Page 1","yes"); 

    SpreadSheetSetRowHeight(Tab1,1,45);
    SpreadsheetSetCellValue(Tab1,"Final Test Report",1,1); SpreadsheetMergeCells(Tab1,1,1,1,10);
    SpreadsheetAddImage(Tab1, A2LA_Logo,"jpg","1,12,2,20"); 
    SpreadsheetSetCellValue(Tab1,"Confidential",1,21); SpreadsheetMergeCells(Tab1,1,1,21,30);
</cfscript>

<cfscript>  
/*********************************************************************** Page 2 ***********************************************************************/
//Create a new Excel spreadsheet object - SpreadsheetNew("Tab name", "yes=2007+ no=2003");
    Tab2 = SpreadsheetNew("Final Report Page 2","yes"); 

    SpreadSheetSetRowHeight(Tab2,1,45);
    SpreadsheetSetCellValue(Tab2,"Final Test Report",1,1); SpreadsheetMergeCells(Tab2,1,1,1,10);
    SpreadsheetAddImage(Tab1, A2LA_Logo,"jpg","1,12,2,20"); 
    SpreadsheetSetCellValue(Tab2,"Confidential",1,21); SpreadsheetMergeCells(Tab2,1,1,21,30);
</cfscript> 

<!--- There must be a better way --->
<cfscript> 
    for(index=1; index LTE 30; index++) {SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Tab1,index,3);}
    for(index=1; index LTE 30; index++) {SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(Tab2,index,3);}
</cfscript> 

<!--- Write the spreadsheet to a file, replacing any existing file, then append the other tabs.  --->
<cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="#theFile#" name="Tab1" overwrite=true>
<cfspreadsheet action="update" filename="#theFile#" name="Tab2">

<!--- Needs to be at the bottom --->
<cfheader name="Content-disposition" value="attachment;filename=Final_Report.xlsx">
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" file="#theFile#">
<!--- Clean up your mess after it is served to the browser --->
<cffile action="delete" file="#theFile#">
```

Comment: IMO `action=update` is kind of buggy. As a troubleshooting step, try saving each tab to a *separate* file with `action=write` (not update). Any change?

Comment: (Edit) RE: *2) image does not appear on the second tab* Because you are adding it to `Tab1` twice. *1) SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth appears to stop working after 21 lines on the second tab* Not sure what you mean by that. `SpreadSheetSetColumnWidth(sheet, column, width)` applies the given with to the entire column. Can you elaborate or post a screen shot?

Comment: @Leigh RE: 1)I'll have to try saving each tab separately tommorow. I suspect that will work for the image. How would I go about merging the tabs into a single workbook?

Comment: @Leigh RE: 2) Tab1 being used for both was a copy and paste error, it still does not work with tab2. RE: 1) I'll add a screen shot tommorow, the width of first 21 columns is correctly set and columns 22-30 remain at the default width.

Comment: The images work when saved separately, so I am guessing it is an `update` bug. My usual recommendation is "do not use `update` if you can avoid it". [Create a single workbook, add multiple sheets and save it with a single `write` action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010472/spreadsheet-cell-formatting/15027832#15027832).

Comment: @Leigh Spot on, do you wan to put that in as an answer. I don't understand why fully, but it works and at the end of the day thats what counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(From the comments)

The images show up when saved separately. So I am guessing it is an `update` bug. My usual recommendation is "do not use update if you can avoid it". [Create a single workbook, add multiple sheets and save it with a single `write` action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010472/spreadsheet-cell-formatting/15027832#15027832).

**Update:** As for why, in your original code, you are creating two separate *workbook* objects. Conceptually think of it like creating two separate Excel files, with one sheet each. Then trying to merge them into one file:

```
     c:/path/to/MyWorkbookNamedTab1.xlsx   

          | Sheet1 / 

     c:/path/to/MyWorkbookNamedTab2.xlsx   

          | Sheet1 /
```

That is different than creating a single workbook, with multiple *sheets* (like in the link above):

```
     c:/path/to/MySingleWorkbook.xlsx   

          | Sheet1 / Sheet2 /
```

There is no easy way to merge separate files (or workbooks). You basically have to copy *everything* from one workbook into another (which is a lot more involved than it sounds). That is what `action=update` does. Somewhere in the copying process it loses one of the images. I am not sure if it that is due to a CF bug one in POI.

In any case, the simplest solution is to avoid the *need* for copying altogether. If you stick with a single *workbook* (and add multiple *sheets* to it) then there is no need for copying or merging. Everything is already contained in one workbook. So all `action=write` has to do is save it to disk, exactly "as is".