# Streaming Excel data using <cfcontent> tag leads to corrupted excel file

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-8

I am trying to send the excel data in the following way

```
<cfsavecontent variable="xlsOutput">
  //My data
</cfsavecontent>

<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="no" showDebugOutput="false">

<cfheader name="ContentDisposition value='attachment;filename="#xls_file#.xls"'>

<cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel" reset="true" variable="#ToBinary( ToBase64(xlsOutput) )#">
```

Though the attachment has come up nicely in the excel format, when I am trying to open it it is throwing the following error

> file has been corrupted and cannot be opened

After this error message, the file is just getting closed without even displaying its content.

I know I am so close, but I am not sure where I am getting it all wrong?

Comment: (Edit) Not being sarcastic, but did you do a search on that error message before posting? There are a LOT of threads on common causes of that error. Usually related to Excel security settings. Also, if that is the actual code, the `cfheader` is shy a closing quote, and there is a typo in the header name.

Comment: Hi Leigh.. Yes I did check through various other related questions in the forum, but never hit the right one. If you could see something related, please direct me to that particular question and you are free to close this thread. I just need a right answer for my genuine question, nothing more nothing less :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your toBinary() and tobase64() might be getting in the way.

Here is a working example using cfspreadsheet, spreadsheetAddColumn, and SpreadsheetAddRows.

```
<!--- FILE --->
<cfset myFile = expandPath('accountslog_#dateFormat(url.datefrom, 'yyyy-mm-dd')#_#dateFormat(dateAdd('d',1,url.dateto), 'yyyy-mm-dd')#.xls') />

<cfset thisSheet = SpreadsheetNew("accountLog") />

<cfquery name="all">
SELECT
        accountlog.dateTime
      , accounts.firstname
      , accounts.lastname
      , accounts.email
      , ... more columns
FROM  accountlog INNER JOIN accounts on accountlog.accountid = accounts.id
WHERE dateTime 
         BETWEEN  <cfqueryparam value="#url.dateFrom#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp"> 
         AND   <cfqueryparam value="#dateAdd('d',1,url.dateTo)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp"> 

    <cfif url.accountid neq ''> 
      AND accounts.id = <cfqueryparam value="#url.accountid#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> 
    </cfif>
ORDER BY datetime
</cfquery>

<cfset thisTable = 'accountLog'>
<cfset thisSheet = SpreadsheetNew( thisTable ) />

<!--- COLUMN HEADERS, droooool --->
<cfloop array="#all.getMetaData().getColumnLabels()#" index="c">
    <cfset spreadsheetAddColumn(thisSheet, c) />
</cfloop>

<!--- ADD THE DATA --->
<cfset SpreadsheetAddRows(thisSheet, all) />

<!--- SAVE THE SHEET --->
<cfspreadsheet
    action="update"
    filename="#myFile#"
    name="thisSheet"
    sheetname="#thisTable#" />

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=#listLast(myFile, '\')#" />
<cfcontent type="application/msexcel" reset="yes" file="#myFile#" deleteFile="yes" />
```

Comment: When generating a temp file, be sure to use *unique* file names. Otherwise, the file can potentially be overwritten by another thread running at the same time. Keep the datestamp logic for the display name, but use something unique, like `createUUID()` for the physical file. Also, if you are just writing a one time file, use SpreadSheetWrite(), or `<cfspreadsheet action=write>`. In my experience [`cfspreadsheet action=update` is buggy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010472/spreadsheet-cell-formatting/15027832#15027832), and is not need here anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Way back we implemented this using the technique below. Now I would look at the **cfspreadsheet** tag.

Here's what we did: save variable to an htm file first, then open it using excel. It'll still give a question to the user that is not very nice looking: "The file you are trying to open is in a different format that specified by extension, etc...". Below is the solution...

```
<cfsavecontent variable="xlsOutput">
  //My data
</cfsavecontent>

<cffile action="WRITE" file="D:\wwwroot\yourwebsite\test.htm" output="#ToBinary( ToBase64(xlsOutput) )#">

<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="xls">
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=report.xls">
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel" file="D:\wwwroot\yourwebsite\test.htm" deletefile="No">
```

Comment: *It'll still give a question to the user...* Replacing one error message with another is not really a solution ;-) Increased security features make newer versions of Excel far less tolerant of the old "trick the browser into thinking html is a spreadsheet" trick. The only reliable solution is to generate a *real* spreadsheet.

Comment: I agree, it's a workaround, not very suitable for commercial application. I don't believe CF worked well with Excel before cfspreadsheet tag... Also, the file generated in my example will actually be opened by excel after prompt vs. the fatal error in the question.

Comment: All depends on the version. Some will still have problems with it. The old html trick *was* a workable option once upon a time.  Unfortunately, with newer versions getting less and less tolerant, it is increasingly likely to cause errors or dire looking warnings, which is not a pleasant user experience. Bottom line, your first suggestion is the better option, ie create a true spreadsheet.